# jQuery - Run a function on change in dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown, and I want to run a jQuery function when-ever a differnet item is selected. This is my current script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$('select[name=dropdown]').change(function() {
    $('#result').html($(this).val());
});
</script>

<div id='result'></div>

<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your script in document.ready handler - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ah5jx/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=dropdown]').change(function() {
        $('#result').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Or simply place your script at the very bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function() {
    $('#result').html($(this).val());
});
});
</script>

<div id='result'></div>

<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @PeaceDealer won't learn from this slab of code - I down-voted as an explanation as to *why* would be helpful.